# how can u control the speed of light?

Tags: particle-physics, visible-light, speed-of-light

Light traveling in a lake goes at 3 km/sec. Please tell me how to limit the speed in the medium (in this case the the lake).

Comment: Dear Anil, I'm having troubles reading your question. Can you make it, somewhat more readable?

Answer (score 4):

[Speed of light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light) $c$ in medium is reduced by its [refractive index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index) $n$.

$$c=\frac{c_0}{n}$$
where $c_0 = 299\,792\,458\frac{m}{s}$ is speed of light in vacuum. You are asking for a material of refractive index $n=1,5$ which is e.g. the glass [BK-7](http://refractiveindex.info/?group=SCHOTT&material=N-BK7).